# BlackBerry - background application to listen starts and foreground app

Tags: blackberry, integration, process, background-application

I would like to create background application which will listen to what applications are started and what are moved to foreground.

Please reply 
If question is not clear will explain again.

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

This is what you can do:

- use [ApplicationManager.getForegroundProcessId()](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.5.0api/net/rim/device/api/system/ApplicationManager.html#getForegroundProcessId%28%29)
- use [ApplicationManager.getVisibleApplications()](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.5.0api/net/rim/device/api/system/ApplicationManager.html#getVisibleApplications%28%29) to get all running apps
- use [ApplicationManager.getProcessId()](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.5.0api/net/rim/device/api/system/ApplicationManager.html#getProcessId%28net.rim.device.api.system.ApplicationDescriptor%29) to search for app by process id
- do this in [TimerTask](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.5.0api/java/util/TimerTask.html) with defined period

  ```
  public class AppListenerApp extends Application {
  int mForegroundProcessId = -1;

  public AppListenerApp() {
      Timer timer = new Timer();
      timer.schedule(mCheckForeground, 2000, 2000);                       
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
      AppListenerApp app = new AppListenerApp();
      app.enterEventDispatcher();
  }

  TimerTask mCheckForeground = new TimerTask() {
      public void run() {
          int id = getForegroungProcessID();
          if(id != mForegroundProcessId)
          {
              mForegroundProcessId = id;
              String name = 
                  getAppNameByProcessId(mForegroundProcessId);
              showMessage(name);
          }
      };
  };

  private int getForegroungProcessID() {
      return ApplicationManager.getApplicationManager()
              .getForegroundProcessId();
  }

  private String getAppNameByProcessId(int id) {
      String result = null;
      ApplicationManager appMan = 
                  ApplicationManager.getApplicationManager();
      ApplicationDescriptor appDes[] = 
                  appMan.getVisibleApplications();
      for (int i = 0; i < appDes.length; i++) {
          if (appMan.getProcessId(appDes[i]) == id) {
              result = appDes[i].getName();
              break;
          }
      }
      return result;
  }

  private void showMessage(String message) {
      synchronized (Application.getEventLock()) {
          Dialog dlg = new Dialog(Dialog.D_OK, message, 
                          Dialog.OK, null, Manager.FIELD_HCENTER);
          Ui.getUiEngine()
                          .pushGlobalScreen(dlg, 1, UiEngine.GLOBAL_QUEUE);
      }
  }
  }
  ```

Comment: Thanks for the reply...

Rather then this is there any Listener API or any kind of Event 
through which we will get the current invoked Foreground Application.

Comment: If its your application, you can always use http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.5.0api/net/rim/device/api/system/Application.html#activate%28%29 event... but in other cases I see no option.