# How to prevent application from launching in Blackberry

Tags: blackberry

I want to prevent any application(like BBM, Gtalk)  from launching when I am clicking on the icon. How is it possible programmatically?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you writing? I virus or something? I don't think you will get any help ith this sort of question here. It sounds very much like you want to do something that will be disruptive for the user.

Comment: I want to block any application from launching. Suppose i am clicking one native application like Blackberry Messenger. So i want to prevent that application from launching through my code. Which API i should use and how to do it??

Comment: And Mr Colin, If you can help, then do it. Or do not get fear about viruses.

Comment: You can't, use BlackBerry Enterprise Server, it's been created exactly for this purpose.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such API to do what you want.

It is possible to disable applications of BlackBerry devices connected to BES (BlackBerry Enterprise Server). It can be done by BES Administrator via creating new rule/policy and sending it to the device.

Comment: Use of GlobalEventListener allows you to know the moment, when the application started. Ok, you get the signal, that BBM is started. And nothing more. What you can do in this case? You cannot intervene in this process, just say ok, I am notified.

Comment: does Blackberry provide any API to interact between two application?

Comment: Yes, it does. But this API is targeted to share information and listen for events between separate applications. There is no way to block an application from another application.

Comment: To communicate - GlobalEventListener interface support, to share information - RuntimeStore class.

Comment: Now suppose i am getting the id of the application which is running in the foreground when i am clicking on a particular Application. So is there any method to prevent that application from launching using that id?

Comment: Can you please check this link- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1984524/blackberry-create-an-application-which-will-lock-another-application-event

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I checked the link you provided. Yes, this may work in some cases.

There is an every second timer task that checks the active app, gets its module name and turns the app to background.

It won't block, but will make "victim" application unusable.

Such "blocking" will drain the device battery and will add "freezing" issues on a device.

Especially in cases when there are many modules.

Why do you need a such blocking?

If you plan to implement a business/commercial application that utilizes such approach I would not buy this app, even I am interested in blocking. It does not look good from my point of view.

Comment: It seems i lost one customer and user of my application!! :)

Comment: No, I am not talking that I am a customer, I told that I would not buy even I am interested in blocking. In real life such goals are achieved via BES administrator console. When you write an app that does blocking described by link you provided, your app becomes a kind of malware.

Comment: yes. I know. But its needed in our application. Whatever thanks for valuable time and help.